# Correlations with alternating second component in R

Tags: r, loops, correlation

(I think this one's fairly straightforward but it's not coming to me, as I'm not terribly comfortable using loops in R.)

I'd like to run a series of `cor()` where one element of the function is the same column, but the second alternates to the next column over. For example, `cor(data$V1, data$V2)` and then `cor(data$V1, data$V3)`, etc. I can't just run a correlation matrix and use `use="complete.obs"` because every comparison has a different number of cases missing.

How can I easily do this in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

```r
lapply(mtcars[,-1], cor, mtcars[,1])
# [[1]]
# [1] -0.852162
# [[2]]
# [1] -0.8475514
# [[3]]
# [1] -0.7761684
# [[4]]
# [1] 0.6811719
# [[5]]
# [1] -0.8676594
# [[6]]
# [1] 0.418684
# [[7]]
# [1] 0.6640389
# [[8]]
# [1] 0.5998324
# [[9]]
# [1] 0.4802848
# [[10]]
# [1] -0.5509251
```

Comment: I get the following error when substituting my data `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : incompatible dimensions`

Comment: That happens when you pass it a `matrix`. From your sample code, it looks like a `data.frame`. Which is it?

Comment: It is a `data.frame`

Comment: I don't know. I've tried it as a `data.frame`, `tbl_df`, and `data.table`, and they all work. While I'm sure there are other ways this error can manifest, the easiest (for me) is to try this on a matrix. Perhaps you can include the output from `dput(head(data))` in your question, it'll provide an unambiguous data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, dumb answer, still can do a correlation matrix but using `use="pairwise.complete.obs`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no missing values, you can just do:

```
set.seed(100)
mat = data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),ncol=100))
colnames(mat) = paste0("V",1:100)
cor(mat[,1],mat[,2:100])
```

If there are missing values:

```
set.seed(100)
mat = matrix(runif(1000),ncol=100)
mat[sample(length(mat),100)] <- NA
mat = data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),ncol=100))
colnames(mat) = paste0("V",1:100)
cor(mat[,1],mat[,2:100],use="p")
```